# Is there a way to connect the Monero Core (GUI wallet) to a remote testnet node?

Tags: development, monero-wallet-gui, testnet

I'm trying to make a liveUSB so people can play with the Monero Core GUI, but I don't want them to download the whole testnet blockchain first just to try it out.

Maybe something like...

monero-core --daemon-address arg

Comment: As this is an old thread, i made a new reddit post with up to date commands [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8jtfhx/private_testnet/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own testnet by running two local nodes, and run a miner locally that mines on the local node blockchain. It has been covered in a reddit thread here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/3x5qwo/how_do_i_make_my_own_testnet_network_with_eg_two/

Demon:

```
/opt/bitmonero/bitmonerod --testnet --testnet-p2p-bind-port 38080 --no-igd --hide-my-port --testnet-data-dir ~/.bitmonero-node2 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:38080
```

Wallet:

```
/opt/bitmonero/simplewallet --testnet --daemon-port 28081
```

Then go into the bitmonero node and start mining with the command:

```
start_mining <your_testnet_address>
```

I tested them out myself, and the above commands work no problem on a a low powered machine, you'll have your own testnet in less than a minute.

There is also another set of instructions here, https://moneroexamples.github.io/private-testnet/ , they are far more comprehensive, and a bit much to include here, but the above commands work and establishes the absolute basics.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an old thread, and the monerod commands have evolve in two years, here's the updated how to:

From your working directory, launch the first daemon:

```
monerod --testnet --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir ~/.bitmonero-node1 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:38080
```

Then launch the second daemon:

```
monerod --testnet --p2p-bind-port 38080 --rpc-bind-port 38081 --zmq-rpc-bind-port 38082 --no-igd --hide-my-port --data-dir ~/.bitmonero-node2 --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --add-exclusive-node 127.0.0.1:28080
```

Those two daemon will be mutually connected.

Launch your favorite monero-wallet-XXX and create a new testnet wallet connected to 127.0.0.1:28081 or 38081
Ensure that your wallet has a starting height of 0 Start mining on one of the two daemon to the public address you created with this wallet.